# Как динамически создавать Vue компоненты по времени?

Tags: vue-cli

Использую **Vue-cli**, файл **App.vue**, можно ли динамически по времени создавать компоненты на странице, и как это сделать?

```
<template>
  <div id="app">
    <Comp /> - Здесь через определенное время добавлять компоненты,
    <Comp /><Comp /><Comp />...
  </div>
</template>

<script>
 import Comp from './components/Comp'
 export default {
  name: 'App',
  components: {
   Comp,
  },
 }
</script>
```

Comment: Можно. Сделать это можно в цикле, например

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Создаете в data свойство, которое будет массивом с количеством элементов равным изначальному количеству компонентов. Рендерите при помощи v-for компоненты перебирая этот массив. А потом через setInterval пушите в свой массив ещё один элемент. Данные реактивные, поэтому будет рендерится каждый раз новое количество компонентов